# MySQLdb Обясните как работать с базами

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

Есть этот код, он по идеи ищет по базе ID того кто прислал сообщение но как мне возвращать не одну строчку с ID а всю строку со всема параметрами которые находятся там типа (id в базе, ID того кто написал, его баланс и тд), дальше как мне сделать изменение в базе например внести этому человеку на баланс игровую валюту?

```
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect("<адресс базы>","<логин>","<пароль>","<имя базы>", charset='utf8')
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT vk_id FROM vk WHERE vk_id = Тут айди для поиска по базе")
row = cursor.fetchone()
print(row)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Читайте в целом про SQL.
Чтобы вместо одной колонки вернуть все достаточно указать *, то есть

```
SELECT * FROM vk WHERE vk_id=id
```

Вернется скорее всего ассоциативный массив значений, где ключ название колонки (не помню как называется в Python, кортеж вроде).

Чтобы поменять что-то в БД SQL, используется команда UPDATE (названия полей взял от балды, так как не знаю какие конкретной у вас в таблице)

```
UPDATE vk SET vk_money=money WHERE vk_id=id
```

ЗЫ: И да, при передаче данных в строку запроса через execute используйте подставноку данных правильно, в стиле

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM vk WHERE vk_id=%s", id)
```

Это убережет вас в будущем от некоторых проблем.

Comment: Спасибо! А можно узнать про подставку данных болые подробно? (На реальном примере желательно)

Comment: я не понял вопроса, я же дал пример вроде

Comment: Я правильно понимаю что если cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM vk WHERE vk_id=%s", id) то id подставится за месть %s?

Comment: да, верно поняли

Comment: Хочу спросить ищё: Почему здесь возникает ошибка?

`ids = 123456789
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO vk (vk_id) VALUES (vk_id=%s)", ids)`

ошибка:
`cursor.execute("INSERT INTO vk (vk_id) VALUES (vk_id=%s)", ids)
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 199, in execute
    args = tuple(map(db.literal, args))
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`

Comment: второй параметр в execute коллекция должна быть. в случае int попробуйте оберунуть в скобки, (ids)

Comment: Огромное спасибо!